# JSF partial response shown plain text on every reload

Tags: jsf, primefaces, partial-response

What can cause this message :

```
<partial-response id="j_id__v_0">
    <changes>
        <update id="j_id__v_0:javax.faces.ViewState:1">i+eTRcNJKFa/X70WEJFydAaAltIQr95KirDWpXlROBzc6LqS</update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

It appears every time I reload the page.

Comment: What u trying to do ? where u get error? What is code? What u tried ?  Where all these details ?

Comment: and what is 'reload the page'? This is an ajax response

Comment: That's not an error page. That's an ajax response. Are you using a 3rd party authentication framework? (e.g. Spring Security, Shiro, etc) Is it JSF ajax aware? I.e. you saw this when you fired a JSF ajax request on an expired session? Instead of asking rhetorical questions please describe how exactly you reproduced it (and thus how exactly we can reproduce it). Also tell JSF impl/version (I can see it's MyFaces, but version is unclear) and sever impl/version. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info